# Jacobian Matrix and dot product question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a question on how the Jacobian matrix is used in a specific example from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).  I present definitions first and then a question.

The Jacobian is defined as:

$J = \begin{bmatrix} \frac {\partial f}{\partial x_1} ... \frac {\partial f}{\partial x_n} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \Delta^T f_1 \\ ... \\ \Delta^T f_m \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac {\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} ... \frac {\partial f_1}{\partial x_n} \\ ... \\ \frac {\partial f_m}{\partial x_1} ... \frac {\partial f_m}{\partial x_n} \end{bmatrix}$

Wiki then says:
$f(y) = f(x) + J(x) \cdot (y - x)$ is the best linear approximation for $f(y)$ for points close to $x$.

**Questions**

1. Does $J(x)$ represent scalar multiplication of the initial point $x$ with the $J$?  I.e. to get the PDs at a point.
2. If (1) above, how does one distinguish this operation from matrix multiplication?
3. For $J(x) \cdot (y - x)$ can the dot product, $\cdot$, be omitted as matrix multiplication will result in the same value?  The third form of $J$ is a matrix and dot product $\cdot$ is a vector operation, so this is confusing.

Comment: BTW, that $\Delta^T f$ should probably be $(\nabla f)^\top$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jacobian matrix $J$ contain partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$ which are themselves functions. The entries of $J(x)$ are these partial derivatives evaluated at $x$, i.e. $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(x)$.

Comment: I thought $J(x)$ would be each entry of $J$ matrix multiplied by $x$.  $J$ seems to represent two different objects.So $J_f(x) = J * x$?

Comment: @Nick No, as I said in my answer, $J(x)$ is a matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is the real number $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(x)$. There is no multiplication going on in the definition of $J(x)$.

Comment: My confusion was over $J(x)$ with $x$ as supplied argument.  Given what you say, a matrix of functions can all each be evaluated with a single argument $(x)$ supplied to the matrix?

Comment: @Nick Yes, that is how I think it should be interpreted: $J$ is a matrix of functions, and $J(x)$ is the matrix consisting of the evaluations of those functions at $x$.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said before, $J(x)$ is the Jacobian matrix at the point $x$, as all the functions depend on $x$. The dot does not below there, as we do not take the dot product of a matrix and a vector. Just delete the dot and multiply the Jacobian matrix by the (column) vector $y-x$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about defining Jacobian for this. This is simple Taylor's theorem:

$$
f_i\left(y\right)=f_i\left(x+(y-x)\right)=f_i\left(x\right)+\sum_j \partial_j f_i\left(x\right)\,\left(y_j-x_j\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(\left|y-x\right|^2\right)
$$

for all $i$